# HTML5 + JS alternative as replacement for Silverlight app

Tags: excel, angularjs, silverlight, user-interface, ria

i have a Silverlight web app which have a lot of functionalities created in data grid views (sorting, filtering, editing and much more)...

Now i decided to convert this app into something much perspective but i stuck on the decision about UI. I would like to use this technologies:

- PHP or Node.JS for API,
- Angular JS for client web APP

But i dont know what to use for UI with large tables and lot of dynamic filtering.

UI can looks like EXCEL UI (App created in Silverlight looks like Excel ).

Thanks for any advice..

Comment: Take a look at my answer....

Answer (score 2):

It can certainly be done with Angular. The project I'm currently working on involves taking dozens of separate systems that manipulate millions of rows of data and modernize those into a web-based app. Angular has served us well for the front-end. We used the combination of Angular and Kendo for controls. The Kendo grid control has all of the features you'd expect for a rich UI, and is also highly extensible and can be customized. We've implemented anything from cells that can be edited in place to hierarchical tree structures and more.

In the case of extremely large UI, you will likely use a combination of server-side page fetching and client side indexing. For example, we have one table that may have a quarter million rows. Obviously this would be a lot to hold in memory, so we just bring back indexes. That allows us to lay out the structure of the grid and then page in data as the user traverses it.

Our company worked extensively with Silverlight over the years so as the web moved away from plug-ins we've had many projects that involve migrating to the web stack. I'd recommend you read our free white paper about Silverlight migration - it is a straight download and doesn't require any registration to access it but covers various pathways from Silverlight to more modern stacks: http://www.wintellect.com/silverlight-update-xaml-html5

Comment: Is the white paper still available somewhere? The link points to a non-existing page.

Comment: Not sure if link will help you now, but might be helpful to someone
https://www.wintellect.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/SilverlightMigration-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I prefer **[AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)** will make things easy for you. `AngularJS` is SPA framework with MVC architecture which has lots of magical power like two way binding, routing, testing, injection

`Angular-xeditable` which is another bundle of  `AngularJS` directives that allows you to create editable elements in such a way that it makes things easier for editing as well as other UI form content manipulation. It is based on ideas of xeditable but was written from scratch to use power of angular and support complex forms / editable grids. Hope you will find it useful.

Link - http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable

Features

1. No need to write any static FORM UI markup
2. fast development, no special FORM markup
3. less number of screens in your application
4. easy adding / removing fields
5. simple backend script for data update
6. more convenient on small forms
7. works in IE7+ and all modern browsers
8. keyboard support (escape/enter/tab)
9. client-side and server-side validation
10. customizible container placement
11. popup and inline modes
12. supported inputs:
13. text
14. textarea
15. select
16. checkbox
17. radio
18. date........etc...